stacking rugplots in seaborn
Is there a way to stack rugplots in Seaborn as in here but below the x-axis?. I have not found anything on the rugplots documentation.

the best documentation is the source code, I'm afraid that you have to read it and find how what you want can be done

Creating the rugplots via seaborn, they can be placed into subplots. Here is an example:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

days = tips['day'].unique()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=5, figsize=(12, 12), sharex=True,
                        gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'height_ratios': [6, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
palette = sns.color_palette('tab10', n_colors=4)
sns.kdeplot(data=tips, x='tip', hue='day', hue_order=days, fill=True, ax=axs[0])
for day, color, ax in zip(days, palette, axs[1:]):
    # draw a rugplot for one specific day, occupying 95% of the plot's height
    sns.rugplot(data=tips[tips['day'] == day], x='tip', height=0.95, color=color, ax=ax)
    ax.set_ylabel(day)
    ax.set_yticks([])  # hide y ticks
    ax.set_facecolor('none')  # make transparent, to see all  x ticks
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.show()


